# how to write xunit test for non static Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker HttpTrigger method

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, moq

I have following function,

```
using FunctionApp.models;
using FunctionApp.service;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace FunctionApp
{
    public class ExampleFunction
    {

        private readonly IBasicService _basicService;

        public ExampleFunction(IBasicService basicService)
        {

            _basicService = basicService;
        }

        [Function("ExampleFunction")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> RunAsync(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "name/{name}/description/{description}")] HttpRequestData req,
            FunctionContext context, string name, string description)
        {

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");


                // Create a Basic object using the route parameters
                var basic = new Basic { Name = name, Description = description };

                // Call the service method to retrieve a Basic object
                var result = await _basicService.Get(basic);

                // Serialize the Basic object to JSON and send it in the response body
                var responseBody = JsonSerializer.Serialize(result);
                await response.WriteStringAsync(responseBody);



            return response;
        }


    }
}
```

This has no issues working as expected when I pass
http://localhost:3068/api/name/TestName/description/TestDesc its working.

then I tried to write **xunit** test for the above function this way

**Attempt 1**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Xunit;
using Moq;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;
using ExampleApp.models;
using ExampleApp.services;
using ExampleApp;

namespace XUnitTest
{
    public class ExampleFunctionTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task ExampleFunction_ReturnsBasicObject()
        {
            // Arrange
            var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<ExampleFunction>>();
            var basicServiceMock = new Mock<IBasicService>();

            var expectedBasic = new Basic { Name = "TestName", Description = "TestDesc" };
            basicServiceMock.Setup(s => s.Get(It.IsAny<Basic>())).ReturnsAsync(expectedBasic);

            var function = new ExampleFunction(loggerMock.Object, basicServiceMock.Object);

            var requestMock = new Mock<HttpRequestData>();
            var responseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseData>();
            requestMock.Setup(r => r.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)).Returns(responseMock.Object);

            var responseStream = new MemoryStream();
            responseMock.SetupGet(r => r.Body).Returns(responseStream);

            var functionContextMock = new Mock<FunctionContext>();
            functionContextMock.SetupGet(c => c.InvocationId).Returns("TestInvocationId");

            // Act
            var result = await function.RunAsync(requestMock.Object, functionContextMock.Object, "TestName", "TestDesc");

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
            responseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                var responseBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                var actualBasic = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Basic>(responseBody);
                Assert.Equal(expectedBasic.Name, actualBasic.Name);
                Assert.Equal(expectedBasic.Description, actualBasic.Description);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This has no compile error but when run test its all getting failed, and showing following error

> Message:  System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: r
> => r.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK) Extension methods (here: HttpRequestDataExtensions.CreateResponse) may not be used in setup /
> verification expressions.

by skipping that method I tried to write this way

**Attempt 2**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Xunit;
using Moq;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;
using ExampleApp.models;
using ExampleApp.services;
using ExampleApp;

namespace XUnitTest
{
    public class ExampleFunctionTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task ExampleFunction_ReturnsBasicObject()
        {
            // Arrange
            var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<ExampleFunction>>();
            var basicServiceMock = new Mock<IBasicService>();

            var expectedBasic = new Basic { Name = "TestName", Description = "TestDesc" };
            basicServiceMock.Setup(s => s.Get(It.IsAny<Basic>())).ReturnsAsync(expectedBasic);

            var function = new ExampleFunction(loggerMock.Object, basicServiceMock.Object);

            var request = Mock.Of<HttpRequestData>();
            var response = new Mock<HttpResponseData>();

            var bodyStream = new MemoryStream();
            response.SetupGet(r => r.Body).Returns(bodyStream);
            response.SetupProperty(r => r.Headers, new HttpHeadersCollection());

            var functionContext = Mock.Of<FunctionContext>(c => c.InvocationId == "TestInvocationId");

            // Act
            var result = await function.RunAsync(request, functionContext, "TestName", "TestDesc");

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);

            bodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(bodyStream))
            {
                var responseBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                var actualBasic = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Basic>(responseBody);
                Assert.Equal(expectedBasic.Name, actualBasic.Name);
                Assert.Equal(expectedBasic.Description, actualBasic.Description);
            }

            // Verify
            basicServiceMock.Verify(s => s.Get(It.Is<Basic>(b => b.Name == "TestName" && b.Description == "TestDesc")), Times.Once);
        }
    }
}
```

but this also gives the following error

> Message:  System.ArgumentException : Can not instantiate proxy of
> class: Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http.HttpRequestData. Could
> not find a parameterless constructor. (Parameter
> 'constructorArguments')
> ---- System.MissingMethodException : Constructor on type 'Castle.Proxies.HttpRequestDataProxy' not found.

Comment: I found this SO post that is similar, the OP found a way to get the context to work.  I tried it and it got me passed the FunctionContext issue at least so my function executed.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67937686/testing-an-azure-function-in-net-5

Comment: The functionContext suggestions you have here got my test working.  This is great.  I am using .net8 v4 functions and I had to add this:

         serviceCollection.AddOptions< WorkerOptions>().Configure(options =>
{
            options.Serializer=new JsonObjectSerializer();
        });

to my service collection "WriteAsJsonAsync" methods to work in my actual function.